# Combining Excel COUNTIFS with aggregate functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say I have an Excel spreadsheet containing student details and dates of courses the student attended. Lets say the row headers are:

Name - Student Grade - Date of course A - Date of course B - Date of course C etc...

Then obviously a separate row per student containing their grade and dates of the courses the student was present in. I want to avoid making modifications to the sheet as the format has been established for a while.

I'm looking for some way of counting all the students with a grade a specific grade, which attended courses between specific dates. For example, count all students with a "C" grade, which attended courses between 1st Jan 2012 to 31st March 2012.

I guess the final formula will be some sort of combination of COUNTIFS and MAX on the date range columns, but I can't see how I can apply this on a row-by-row basis.

All suggestions much appreciated!

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: if 1 student attended 1 course in February and 2 in March, should he count as 1 for February and 1 for March? or 0 for Feb and 1 for Mar? or 1 for Feb and 2 for Mar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have grades in `B2:B100` and dates in 5 columns `C2:G100` then you can use this formula to count the number of students with a specific grade who took courses in a specific date period.

`=SUMPRODUCT((MMULT((C$2:G$100>=J2)*(C$2:G$100<=K2)*(B$2:B$100=I2),{1;1;1;1;1})>0)+0)`

where `J2` and `K2` are the start and end dates of the period (`1-Jan-2012` and `1-Mar-2012`) and `I2` is a specific grade (`C`)

the `{1;1;1;1;1}` part depends on the number of date columns, so if there are 7 date columns then you need to change that to `{1;1;1;1;1;1;1}`.....or you make the formula dynamically adjust by using this version

`=SUM((MMULT((C$2:G$100>=J2)*(C$2:G$100<=K2)*(B$2:B$100=I2),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C2:G100))^0)>0)+0)`

The latter formula, though, is an "array formula" which you need to confirm with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

**Update**

For the number of distinct grades within a specific date range then assuming you have a finite list of possible grades then list those somewhere on the worksheet, e.g. `M2:M10` and then you can use this "array formula"

`=SUM(1-ISNA(MATCH(M$2:M$10,IF(MMULT((C$2:G$100>=J2)*(C$2:G$100<=K2),{1;1;1;1;1}),B$2:B$100),0)))`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

Comment: This works brilliantly, thanks. Used the first one as the columns with the dates are fixed. For bonus points, how would I go about getting the distinct number of rows within the range? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify - I'm looking for the number for distinct grades for students which attended courses between specific dates.

Comment: For the number of distince grades within specific dates, maybe try this with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER: `=COUNT(FREQUENCY(IF((C$2:G$100>=J2)*(C$2:G$100<=K2),MATCH(B$2:B$100,B$2:B$100,0)),ROW(B$2:B$100)-MIN(ROW(B$2:B$100)))^0)`.

Comment: When I just tried pasting the formula above, it seems there is an issue due to an extra line return character being inserted by the comment. Retyping this part should fix it: `,0)`.

Comment: @ lori_m - yes, that works for me +1 @Mr_Chris also revised my answer to show another way, see above

Comment: Thanks again guys - top stuff! Much appreciate the answers provided.